# While running event API on Jmeter, the server is updating event on old time frame

Tags: api, server, jmeter

What I am doing is, I have recorded a download event from APP on Jmeter, when ever i am running this API on Jmeter, a server where any download event is recorded, is showing OR increment that download on that specific time when it was recorded.
How can I use this to get updated data on server when Jmeter is running.

Also need some information on to how to add different valid users on Jmeter.

Thanks,
Abhi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My expectation is that you pass a hard-coded timestamp as a request parameter so you need to figure out the parameter value and substitute the hard-coded timestamp with [__time() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__time) which produces current time in different formats controllable via [SimpleDateFormat](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) patterns.

Check out [How to Use JMeter Functions](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-use-jmeter-functions-part-iii) article for comprehensive explanation

---

In regards to adding valid users, normally people stick to users which already exist in the system and use [CSV Data Set Config](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config) to give each JMeter virtual user unique credentials of the real user.

If your application doesn't have that much users you might want to setup a separate JMeter script to get them created as re-using one login with large number of threads is not a good practice.

Comment: Thanks Dmitri, but how could I use the same API to set up a seprate Jmeter script? and also I am unable to get how to pass userid and pw to that API. In recording it might be taking as logged in API,. Please let me know how can I pass parameters to event API,